# Why does this regular expression not match in Puppet?

Tags: regex, puppet

The aim to match the hostname `CI-TEST-POC` using a regular expression in Puppet. Neither:

```
if $hostname == /CI-(\[A-Z\]+)-POC/ {
  notice("Welcome to web server number $1")
}
```

nor:

```
if $hostname =~ /CI-(\[A-Z\]+)-POC/ {
  notice("Welcome to web server number $1")
}
```

matches. Why does this regular expression not match in Puppet?

Comment: Have you tried using an online regexp tester e.g. https://regex101.com  ?

Comment: Tried it. ^CI-([A-Z]+)-POC$ seems perfectly okay in the online. But no luck with puppet script.

Comment: Okat got it.
if $hostname =~ /^CI-([A-Z]+)-POC$/ {
    notice("matches REGEXP XXX $1")
  }else {
    notice("DIDN'T matches REGEXP XXX")
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it.

```
if $hostname =~ /^CI-([A-Z]+)-POC$/ {
  notice("matches REGEXP XXX $1")
} else { 
  notice("DIDN'T matches REGEXP XXX") 
}
```

Comment: Please add to always use a regexp tester as indicated by @AlexHarvey, before creating the actual code.

Comment: So your problem was that you wrote the conditionals wrong, or that you wrote the regex wrong, or both?